# Android: How to build a .apk from the terminal?

Tags: android, android-build

I am developing a dynamic app generator, so I would need to run the command on a runtime basis using Java on a server

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the Android Developer site:

[Managing Projects from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

[Building APK from Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

You will need [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) to build from the command line. Once you have that you can create the APK like this:

**Windows:**

```
> gradlew.bat assembleRelease
```

**Unix:**

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

> This creates your Android application .apk file inside the project
>   bin/ directory, named -unsigned.apk.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suggest to not using "link only answers".

Comment: @GrizzlyNetch I added more details to the answer.

Comment: Good job, if I did understand any of this (I'm from iOS world :) ), I'd give you a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you may rely on Android SDK, it is as simple as to generate build.xml and some properties file and invoke ant.

You may generate an android project by command android for reference.

Answer (score 1):

`ant release` command builds release APK